# Why is mosquitto-go-auth not caching auth requests?

Tags: mosquitto

I'm running [iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth:latest-mosquitto_2.0.14](https://hub.docker.com/layers/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth/latest-mosquitto_2.0.14/images/sha256-4df99179632b2c86f6e7d9b91a00414c7dff95f3b8933f314c59cc08b5a29e29?context=explore) with this config file

```sh
persistence true
persistence_location /persistence

per_listener_settings true

# ---- Default listener, SSL/TLS Support

listener 8883
# install script will create a symlink for these:
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key

# Common Name (CN) from the client certificate to be used instead of the
# MQTT username for access control purposes
use_identity_as_username true
require_certificate true

auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/go-auth.so
auth_opt_backends js

auth_opt_cache true
auth_opt_cache_type go-cache
auth_opt_auth_cache_seconds 300
auth_opt_acl_cache_seconds 300
auth_opt_auth_jitter_seconds 30
auth_opt_acl_jitter_seconds 30

auth_opt_js_user_script_path /etc/mosquitto/auth/user.js
auth_opt_js_superuser_script_path /etc/mosquitto/auth/superuser.js
auth_opt_js_acl_script_path /etc/mosquitto/auth/acl.js
```

But when I make the same `sub` request twice with the same user, the specified `superuser` and `acl` scripts get called both times, not just once (validated via `console.log` output in those scripts). I want it to cache the result the first time and not repeat the evaluations the second time, which I believe is what the auth cache is supposed to do.

Comment: Those are questions for the auth plugin, not mosquitto, everything after `auth_opt_` is interrupted by the plugin not mosquitto.

Comment: Yes, I know, but there is no tag for the mosquitto auth plugin.